# How to edit filtered rows in interactive report in apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to edit rows in interactive report. Before or after filtering. I have made column link in select query using ''edit_link but in Regions > Interactive Report > Column Attributes > [Column Name (edit_link)] > Column Link section i can't send data using item because there is no items on list to pick in page with interactive report. In normal report there are items i can select to read data from and send to (item and value boxes). Is it any solution to edit filtered rows?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that come to mind to accomplish this.  I will explain an approach that starts off with where your prompt left off.

### 1. Create a FORM Page

This is to edit a record from your Interactive Report.  I assume that the query behind your IR is not a complex, multi table query, which will not work with this approach unless you build this form on a Stored Procedure (instead of Apex's automatic DML functionality).

#### Build a Form on the Table from the IR

From the *Application Builder* menu, CREATE a New FORM.  Select "Form on a Table or View".  Select the TABLE to build this form on and fill in the information required to map it.  You will be asked to identify the PRIMARY KEY of the table from your Interactive Report.

#### Set All Branching Activity to Return to the IR

When Prompted for "After Page Submit And Processing Branch to Page" and "When Cancel Button Pressed Branch to this Page"  Choose the page number of your Interactive Report. Any activity on this page, when done (whether through CANCEL or SUBMIT and process), you will want it to go back.

### 2. Set Column "Edit Link" Properties

Under the **Column Link** section, set the target to "Page in this Application", and add the page of the form previously created.  Items should now show in your popup.  Select the Page Item from your Forms page that corresponds to your Table's Primary Key.  The value can be derived in some way, or just point to a the column it came from. (i.e., #MY_KEY_ID#).

*The key part that was probably missing for you was the existence of the edit form required to modify the record.  That is not an automatically created feature when you create an IR report.*